# A permanent portable Magic Circle

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, magic, summoning

So, a Wizard just got their hands on the Planar Binding spell line, and wants to start utilizing it. Said Wizard also likes to be self-sufficient AND is invested in their alignment - which means they don't want to ask other people for help and REALLY don't want to start casting spells of opposed alignment. But in order to Bind a creature of *the same* alignment, you have to cast a Magic Circle spell of *opposed* alignment, which even carries an opposed [alignment] descriptor.

After thinking about it for some time, I've realized that the best way to do this by-the-book is to have a magic item that specifically works as a Magic Circle that's turned inside. **The question is if there's an item like this already or if I'll have to make a custom one.**

I know that there's the Binder-only Seal of the Spirit in Tome of Magic that serves a similar function, but it works strictly for Vestiges.

Comment: Not an answer to the question as posed (how to get a permanent, portable magic circle), but I don't think there's any restriction on *wizards* casting spells opposed to their own alignment. That restriction only applies to clerics.

Comment: Casting spells opposite of your alignment cause an alignment shift so while there are no mechanical problems if the wizard is attached to his alignment then repeated casting is off the table as eventually his alignment would shift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stronghold Builders Guidebook (3.0, but not updated, thus still legal in 3.5) has permanent magic circles as an architectural feature which can be purchased for mobile strongholds. When magic circles are created, it can be specified at the time of creation if it is inward facing or outward facing.

> The magical architecture is called an **Engraved Circle of Protection (alignment)**, and the market price is 7500 gp. It specifies that it can be outward facing for protection, or inward facing for imprisoning. It functions as the spell, except that it is a permanent form of the spell. It can be from 3 feet to 20 feet across, and the size cannot be changed once it is crafted.
>
> See pages 75 and 76 of the SBG for details on Engraved Magic Circles. Also see the notes on Magical Architecture on pages 69 and 70.

Note that a clever person will double up on the circles, having two circles, one larger than the other. The inner circle faces inward, the outer circle faces outward with a gap in the middle, for safety.

Note that "mobile stronghold" is a very flexible term and can be applied to a wagon, a hut, a castle, a boat, a tower, or even a floating platform.

Technically speaking you could pop a slab of durable material down a portable hole, engrave the circle on it, and that would work too.

Not to mention that a mobile stronghold would likely appeal to such a self sufficient character and/or player.

---

I can testify that when my group found out my character's mini mobile stronghold had a dungeon cell in it where we could keep our prisoners, they were suddenly a whole lot more supportive of my character, lol.

Comment: Okay, this is a pretty solid solution, and while a "Mobile Fortress" might be a tad out of reach for a 9-11 level character (the levels arcanists get Planar Binding), a slab of granite with a carved Circle from this book would be a pretty decently priced thing

Comment: Yeah, an entire fortress gets pricey fast. That's why I stuck with a relatively small boat for my first one. The price can be offset somewhat by the landlord feat in the same book, but that has its own impacts on your campaign. Use with wisdom.